# Dropdownlist data not insert in query in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I placed five dropdownlists and three textboxes in asp.net webpage. The value select in dropdownlist and insert in textboxes are the values to be insert in query for where condition. Now the problem is that when I press search button for execution the values from text boxes are inserted in query but the dropdownlist values remain empty, and the result is not showing. I check code for dropdownlist like:

```
    ddlChannel.SelectedValue;
    ddlChannel.Text;
    ddlChannel.SelectedItem;
```

but not any selected value is inserted from the query. Either problem in on pageLoad. I use `Page_Prerender` method to load dropdownlist from database through query execution.  Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Can yu show your code on how you are creating the dropdown options?

Comment: this is the cide link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176163/dropdownlist-data-not-insert-in-query/13177699#13177699

Answer (score 0):

the selected values from your dropdownlists are most likely reset on postback ( when you click search button )

you can use the following code to avoid resetting your dropdownlists

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //Bind dropdown lists logic
}
```

Comment: I use that code on pageLoad event 
but after postback the dropdownlist become empty and also ddl values remain empty too.

Comment: I also think that due to postback event values remain empty in dropdownlist but textboxes values remain in.

Comment: you shouldn't use IsPostback in Load if you populate the ddl in preRender! Could you show code for preRender and load

Comment: So soory friends. I write the enableviewstate=false on asp.net Form tag. My problems solved now :). Extremely soory for this friends

Answer (score 0):

you have to set controls autopostback property true, eventvalidation set false on page pl